# Hidden anchor link falling in next line once show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you tell me why the anchor link with class "edit" falling in next line the next time it is being displayed/showed?

To replicate click, edit button and then save button on jsfiddle link below.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr969xry/)

HTML

```
<div id="con">

<a href="#" id="283" class="trash">Delete</a>
<a href="#" id="edit_283" class="edit">Edit</a> 
<a href="#" id="save_283" class="save">Save</a></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".edit").click(function(){

var ID=$(this).attr('id');

var RemoveIDedit = ID.replace('edit_','');

$(this).hide();

$("#save_"+RemoveIDedit).show();

   });





$(".save").click(function(){

var ID=$(this).attr("id");

var RemoveIDsave = ID.replace('save_','');

$(this).hide()

$("#edit_"+RemoveIDsave).show();
```

Comment: By default `<a>` tag is an inline element so it shows inline with Delete but when you do a `.show()` it makes it `display: block`. You can replace the show with this `$("#edit_"+RemoveIDsave).css('display','inline-block');
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kr969xry/2/)

instead of this

```
$("#edit_"+RemoveIDsave).show();
```

Try this

```
$("#edit_"+RemoveIDsave).css("display","inline");
```

Comment: Thanks for sample demo!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `display: block;`, replace it with `display: inline;`

Please use following code, I've edited this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".edit").click(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var RemoveIDedit = ID.replace('edit_', '');
    $(this).hide();
    $("#save_" + RemoveIDedit).css('display', 'inline');

  });



  $(".save").click(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var RemoveIDsave = ID.replace('save_', '');
    $(this).hide()
    $("#edit_" + RemoveIDsave).css('display', 'inline');

  });

});
```

```css
.save {
    display: none;
  }
  .save,
  .edit {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  #con {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
    boreder-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con"> <a href="#" id="283" class="trash">Delete</a><a href="#" id="edit_283" class="edit">Edit</a>  <a href="#" id="save_283" class="save">Save</a>
</div>a
```

Comment: Do you still need `.show()` if you're updating the CSS directly?

Comment: Why does this only affect the `Edit` link, not `Save`?

Comment: Check now, I've updated the code. sorry for inconvenience. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:absolute for .edit and .save from your stylesheet.

Comment: I put that as intended so edit and save link will be in same position, thanks for advice though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visibility property instead of display
css

```
 .save {
              visibility:hidden;
              }



.save, .edit {
position: absolute;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".edit").click(function(){
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var RemoveIDedit = ID.replace('edit_','');
$(this).css("visibility","hidden");
$("#save_"+RemoveIDedit).css("visibility","visible");

           });



            $(".save").click(function(){
var ID=$(this).attr("id");
var RemoveIDsave = ID.replace('save_','');
$(this).css("visibility","hidden");
$("#edit_"+RemoveIDsave).css("visibility","visible");

           });

              });
```

Hope this may satisfy you